# Bijection between lists and sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Multiplication Principle as given in my textbook:

> Consider two element lists for which there are $n$ choices for the first element, and for each choice of the first element there are $m$ choices for the second element. Then the number of such lists is $nm$.

Is there some kind of bijective function that we could use to extend the rule above to sets since we seem to be able to use it with sets as well?

Answer (score 0):

Except under very special circumstances, there will be no such bijection.

In the list, the $n$ choices for the first element may be disjoint from the $m$ choices for the second element (plus, this is ordered).  Whereas for sets, elements of the set are un-ordered and come from the same "universal" set.

Comment: Consider Vandermond's Identity: $ \binom{m + n}{k} = \sum_{j = 0}^k \binom {m}{j} \binom{n}{k - j}$ where $m, n \ge 0$. How do we justify the multiplication in the right side of the equation?

Comment: What is it that you are hoping to find?  There are nice ways of counting sets/subsets which use (essentially) the multiplication rule (then divide out by the number of times a set was counted).

Comment: @shake-up, Are you asking why the identity is true?  It is just a count of subsets in two different ways.

Comment: On the right side of the identity the numbers of subsets of $m, n$ are multiplied. Why not add them, for example? I just want to understand the reason behind multiplying cardinality of sets.